# find objectType from id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm not getting the Boolean type?

Here is my code, what i m doing wrong?

```
id val = [ dict objectForKey:key ];

if ([ val isKindOfClass:[ NSString class ] ] )
   print "string";
else if( [ val  isKindOfClass:[ NSNumber class ] ] )
   print "number";
else if( [ val  isKindOfClass:[ BOOL class ] ] )
   print "bool";
```

Not getting the boolean type.

Comment: You cant store BOOL in an NSDictionary. See docs. (When you parse a JSON, booleans will be stored as NSIntegers 0 and 1.)

Comment: Besides, your print statements are bad.

Comment: As You're new to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) also read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).
When you found a correct answer you have to accept it and up vote.

Comment: @ilmiacs NSIntegers dont work, wither ;) they are stored as `[NSNumber nuberWithBOOL:]`

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518761/get-type-of-nsnumber You can create a NSNumbers and then check its objCType.

Comment: @Ahti Yes sorry, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You cant save `BOOL` value in `NSDictionary` directly because it is not an object. So first you will have to change it in `NSNumber` then save it in `NSDictionary` and then compare `isKindOfClass:[NSNumber Class]` instead of comparing the `[BOOL class]`.

Example:-

```
BOOL value = YES;
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value],@"Bool", nil];

id val = [dict valueForKey:@"Bool"];
if([val isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    //NSNumber Class
}
```

**EDIT:**

You cant cast a `BOOL` value into `NSString` directly. If you want `BOOL` value in `NSString` format you will have to make your own methods. Here is a small example of this using `macro`.

Define this `macro` in which class you want to cast a `BOOL` value to `NSString`.

```
#define NSStringFromBOOL(aBOOL) aBOOL? @"YES" : @"NO"
```

Then simply call this -

```
NSString *bool_string = NSStringFromBOOL(YES);
NSLog(@"%@",bool_string);
```

It will print `YES` instead of '1'.

Comment: hey i want to set boolean value as Yes/No format not in the 0 and 1, I have string , number , and bool value so how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL` is not a class nor an Objective-C object type. It's a scalar, typedeffed from a C primitive type (`signed char`). You can't use it like this.