# How to know the type of number stored on NSNumber?

Tags: ios, nsnumber

How to know the type of the number is stored on `NSNumber` object? In other words, is there a way to check the entry type of the number when `NSNumber` was created?

Let's suppose that I store some random number on `NSNumber` object:

```
NSNumber *intNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Of course I will want to retrieve it using the `intValue` method later:

```
int theValue = [intNumber intValue];
```

But if the number came from a unknown source, an API JSON response or whatever and I just parse it as a `NSDictionary`, resulting on something like this:

```
{
    "Some key" : 1,
    "Some other key" : 74.1234
}
```

We can assume that `Some key` has an `int` value, while `Some other key` has a `double`.

Is there a way to check which type is the appropriated to parse the value on each key? Something that I could use like:

```
for (NSNumber *number in _arrayOfNumbers) {

    if (/*number is integer*/) {

        //do integer stuff

    } else if (/*number is double*/) {

        //do double stuff
    }
}
```

I don't know if I would need to use this on a real situation, but I was just wondering If there is a way to check the "entry type" of the number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518761/get-type-of-nsnumber

Comment: `if([number isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CFNumberGetType`

```
CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)number);
```

You can throw this value into a switch statement for each value of the enum `CFNumberType`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! I don't remember to have seen that on NSNumber docs. Thanks.