# How to tell the difference between a Boolean and an NSNumber in CoreData

Tags: ios, json, core-data, serialization, kvc

I have some parsing code I'm using for serialising and deserialising objects from our web service and I've hit a bit of a problem when serialising booleans.

The serialisation looks like this:

```
 - (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentationWithMapping:(NSDictionary *)mappingDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (id key in[mappingDictionary allKeys])
    {
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];

        if ((value != [NSNull null]) && (![value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) && (value != nil))
        {
            [dictionary setObject:value forKey:mappingDictionary[key]];
        }
    }

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
}
```

The problem is that when I call valueForKey: on my NSManagedObject and then add this to my dictionary I end up with the value being set as if I was calling:

```
[dictionary setObject:@1 forKey:mappingDictionary[key]];
```

instead of:

```
[dictionary setObject:@YES forKey:mappingDictionary[key]];
```

This means that when I turn this into JSON, in the next stage, I'm sending 1 instead of true to the server.

So what I need is a way of retaining the fact that this is an NSNumber representing a bool as opposed to a number. I've tried asking for the class but I just get back NSNumber. Is there a way I can retain this automatically or failing that, is there a way I can consult the model to see what the attribute type was set to?

Comment: The underline class that manges boolean is __NSCFBoolean but I would not recommend a check with it, since NSNumber is a class cluster

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518761/get-type-of-nsnumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each entity has its metadata stored in `NSEntityDescription` and `NSAttributeDescription`. You can access them from `NSManagedObject` in a following way:

```
//you can put this inside the for loop
NSAttributeDescription *attributeDescription = self.entity.attributesByName[key];
if(attributeDescription.attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType) {
  //it is a boolean attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending a call to the server, you could do like this:
`[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:mappingDictionary[key]];` ;
Or another way, you can model server side to retain its value as Boolean, and at that time, just need to send like this `[dict setValue:YES] forKey:mappingDictionary[key]];`

Hope it could help

Comment: This correctly produces a key which will be output as a bool in JSON. However, my problem is that I've got a serialisation method in an abstract superclass so I need the parsing to infer the type from the object.