# How to check dictionary value to be exactly a Bool?

Tags: swift

Let's say we have something like this:

```
  static func convertBoolToString(source: [String: AnyObject]) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    var destination = [String:AnyObject]()
    for (key, value) in source {
      switch value {
      case is Bool:
        destination[key] = "\(value as! Bool)"
      default:
        destination[key] = value
      }
    }

    if destination.isEmpty {
      return nil
    }
    return destination
  }
```

The problem is that if value is `Double` or `Int` or anything convertible to `Bool` it will pass the first `case`.
Pls, check the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

How to check the value to be exactly and only a `Bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky problem. Note that neither `Bool`, `Double` or `Int` are `AnyObject`, they are all value types. That means they are represented in the dictionary as `NSNumber`. However, `NSNumber` can convert any value it holds to a `Bool`.

Checking which type is inside `NSNumber` is not easy. One way to check is to compare references with the result of `NSNumber(bool:)` constructors because `NSNumber` returns always the same instance:

```
func convertBoolToString(source: [String: AnyObject]) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    var destination = [String:AnyObject]()

    let theTrue = NSNumber(bool: true)
    let theFalse = NSNumber(bool: false)

    for (key, value) in source {
        switch value {
        case let x where x === theTrue || x === theFalse:
            destination[key] = "\(value as! Bool)"
        default:
            destination[key] = "not a bool"
        }
    }

    if destination.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
    return destination
}

let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["testA": true, "testB": 0, "testC": NSNumber(bool: true)]
print("Converted: \(convertBoolToString(dictionary))")
```

For other options, see [get type of NSNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518761/get-type-of-nsnumber)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version:

```
static func convertBoolToString(_ source: [String: Any]?) -> [String:Any]? {
    guard let source = source else {
        return nil
    }
    var destination = [String:Any]()
    let theTrue = NSNumber(value: true)
    let theFalse = NSNumber(value: false)
    for (key, value) in source {
        switch value {
        case let x as NSNumber where x === theTrue || x === theFalse:
            destination[key] = "\(x.boolValue)"
        default:
            destination[key] = value
        }
    }
    return destination
}
```